# ReactJS: Child component not triggering parent component rerender on action click

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to refactor my component and extract the list items into a separate child component.

The original code below (not refactored) works:

```
// ListContainer.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, deleteItem } from '../actions/itemActions';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class ListContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();
  }

  deleteAction = (id) => {
        console.log('this.props: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props));
        this.props.deleteItem(id);
  }

  render() {

        const { items } = this.props.item;
    
        return(
          <Container>
            <ListGroup>
              <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                {
                  items.map((item, i) => (
                <CSSTransition key={item._id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
                    <ListGroupItem>
                      <Button
                        className="remove-btn"
                        color="danger"
                        size="sm"
                        onClick={e => this.deleteAction(item._id, e)}>
                        &times;
                      </Button>
                      {item.name} {item._id}
                    </ListGroupItem>
                  </CSSTransition>
                  ))
                }
              </TransitionGroup>
            </ListGroup>
          </Container>
        );
      }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  item: state.item
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getItems: () => dispatch(getItems()),
  deleteItem: id => dispatch(deleteItem(id)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListContainer);
```

The refactored code below doesn't work:

Clicking on the delete button does not rerender the new list correctly even though the action is dispatched, the redux store is updated and the API callout succeeds.

```js
// New ListContainer.js

// Same imports

// Extracted component
const ListElement = props => {
  const { del } = props;
  const { _id } = props.item;
  const { name } = props.item;
  return (
    <CSSTransition key={_id} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
      <ListGroupItem>
        <Button
          className="remove-btn"
          color="danger"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => del(_id)}>
          &times;
        </Button>
        {name} {_id}
      </ListGroupItem>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
}

// Refactored parent component
class ListContainer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getItems();
  }

  del = (id) => {
    this.props.deleteItem(id);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props.item;

    return(
      <Container>
        <ListGroup>
          <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
            {
              items.map((item, i) => (
                <ListElement key={i} item={item} del={ id => this.del(id) } />
              ))
            }
          </TransitionGroup>
        </ListGroup>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

// Same redux connector
```

Why is the ListContainer component not rendered properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lesson in debugging (and persistence): generate lots of ideas and systematically test them. After looking in every possible corner of the application, I found the issue! The issue was in the presentation layer.  **react-transition-group** didn't work as expected after refactoring. Removing **TransitionGroup** and **CSSTransition** fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of why you shouldn't use the array index as a key when rendering a list of components. React can't properly detect changes.

Use something unique about the item as the `key` prop. If they don't have anything unique, generate a unique id and assign it to them first.

You can do a bit of research about why using the index as a key causes the issues your seeing, if you're curious. Would probably be a good idea.

Comment: If the `id` property is unique for each item, use that as the `key` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Jayce. I have tried that already - it does make any difference.

Comment: Can you add your reducer code that deletes the item from the store?

Comment: Sure, see the updated code snippet. The problem is that the error happens only when I try to show each item using a separate child component. If I move the child component's JSX back to the parent - everything works. So, I must be missing something...

Comment: In your `ListContainer` render inside the map, you have `<ListElement ... del={ id => this.del(id) } />` where is that `id` argument coming from? Shouldn't it be `<ListElement ... del={ id => this.del(item._id) } />`? Since it's a property of the item object (and apparently that key has an underscore too by the looks of it).

Comment: It's passed through the child component. But I have tried changing it as you've suggested - no difference.

Comment: The delete action works fine - redux store is updated every time I click delete, but the rendering doesn't work.